# Strange error in chromium during development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, chromium, nvd3.js

I am using D3.js + nvd3.js lib for making charts and facing the error in chromium. It doesnot seems to break anything but not sure whats wrong.

```
 Error: Problem parsing d="MZ"
```

I haven't seen anything like this before. Found nothing relevant googling. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this bug on my nv.d3  fork: [@github:arlm/nvd3/aggregated-pull-requests](http://github.com/arlm/nvd3/tree/aggregated-pull-requests) or [@github:arlm/nvd3/fix](http://github.com/arlm/nvd3/tree/fix)